# What is the polite way to deal with comments which augment answers?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

Sometimes, when I answer a question, someone will post a comment under it suggesting an augmentation or an improvement of the answer, usually adding more information.

In these cases, should I just let the comment stand as an augmentation of my answer, or edit my answer to incorporate the content of the comment?

The advantage of the first is that the person who comments will get credit for that addition. The advantage of the second is that it is clear that the information is useful, since it is in the actual answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you really feel that the comment adds more to the answer and makes it a even better answer than it currently is, you can post a small credit note to the user in your answer, just before  the part where you incorporate the suggestion.

If some information is really useful/adding to the answer, it should always be in the answer and not in the comments, because **comments are second class citizens here on SE**. You never know when they might be removed.

Something like this:

> As @UserXYZ suggested,
>
> This part of answer comes from that comment.

You can additionally even give the link of the comment but that wouldn't be very useful in case the comment is removed. Nevertheless, it is always good to give the due credit as everybody is out here to help each other :)

Comment: This happens a lot over on [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21032). Example: *"Thanks to @Blender for shaving 8 characters."*

Comment: In fact, we are *so* out to help each other that I just edited a competing answer to my own on this question to make this one better :P

Answer (score 7):

I would upvote the comment and reply with an acknowledgement to the comment, and I would also edit the answer. By doing this, you:

1. Show that you have taken action to fix the problem
2. Show that the commenter deserves credit
3. Make the answer more complete and correct.

Of course, if the suggestion is incorrect, I would just reply to the comment with an explanation why.

Answer (score 3):

If someone comments your answer with an improvement. You are free to edit that into your answer. You can even credit them if you like.

Comments have a more volatile nature than answers.

Besides, if the other user wanted to post its own answer he or she probably did.